# dynamic css animation on radio button

Tags: html, css, radio-button

Is there a way to have the `.switch__indicator` cover each `label` without having to set a fixed width for the `.switch` container?

I'm using `translate3d` but this requires me to set the width of the container and I want to keep it dynamic.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.switch:before {
  content: '  ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.switch__label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  border: 3px solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 200ms ease-out;
}

.switch__indicator {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: -.5rem;
  left: 0;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 600ms cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.94, 0.09, 0.97), background 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.14, 1.03);
  transform: translate3d(1rem, 0, 0);
}

.switch input#one:checked~.switch__indicator {
  transform: translate3d(1.2rem, 0, 0);
}

.switch input#two:checked~.switch__indicator {
  transform: translate3d(5.5rem, 0, 0);
}

.switch input#three:checked~.switch__indicator {
  transform: translate3d(9.6rem, 0, 0);
}

.switch input#four:checked~.switch__indicator {
  transform: translate3d(14rem, 0, 0);
}

.switch input[type="radio"]:not(:checked),
.switch input[type="radio"]:checked {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="switch">
    <input id="one" type="radio" name='thing' value='a' checked="checked" />
    <label for="one" class="switch__label">One</label>

    <input id="two" type="radio" name='thing' value='b' />
    <label for="two" class="switch__label">Two</label>

    <input id="three" type="radio" name='thing' value='c' />
    <label for="three" class="switch__label">Three</label>

    <input id="four" type="radio" name='thing' value='d' />
    <label for="four" class="switch__label">Four</label>

    <div class="switch__indicator"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say you want it to 'cover' each of the inputs... are you looking for four different circles each contained within the squares, one distorted oval, or one giant circle that completely hides the edges of the squares?

Comment: I want the circle to work exactly like it does, but have it perfectly align over each input when selected.

Comment: If you want to keep the current animation of the ball, I think you might need javascript to know the position of label.

Answer (score 3):

Its a bit difficult to calculate the exact space between labels as `label` are inline elements which have a space around them to aligned, so better to use `flexbox` here to remove the space and then use `margin` to give space between them.

Now you will need to calculate the exact `translateX` value which will be sum of `border` value, `width` of label and the `margin` value between them.

Also you don't need of `translate3d` here just use `translateX` and use `calc()` to calculate the exact amount of space.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  display: flex;
}

.switch:before {
  content: '  ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.switch__label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  border: 3px solid;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 200ms ease-out;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.switch__indicator {
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 600ms cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.94, 0.09, 0.97), background 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.14, 1.03);
  transform: translate3d(1rem, 0, 0);
}

.switch__label:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.switch input#one:checked~.switch__indicator {
  transform: translateX(calc(1rem + 3px));
}

.switch input#two:checked~.switch__indicator {
  transform: translateX(calc(5rem + 13px));
}

.switch input#three:checked~.switch__indicator {
  transform: translateX(calc(9rem + 23px));
}

.switch input#four:checked~.switch__indicator {
  transform: translateX(calc(13rem + 33px));
}

.switch input[type="radio"]:not(:checked),
.switch input[type="radio"]:checked {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="switch">
    <input id="one" type="radio" name='thing' value='a' checked="checked" />
    <label for="one" class="switch__label">One</label>
    <input id="two" type="radio" name='thing' value='b' />
    <label for="two" class="switch__label">Two</label>
    <input id="three" type="radio" name='thing' value='c' />
    <label for="three" class="switch__label">Three</label>
    <input id="four" type="radio" name='thing' value='d' />
    <label for="four" class="switch__label">Four</label>
    <div class="switch__indicator"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```